# I have array in database field and want to search like devices where 5G is Yes value using Query Builder Laravel and display Products in view Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, search, find, query-builder

I have a column in database in which I store an array to store device specification in an array I think its array in a array now i want to get devices where for example technology 5G is Yes Value here is the below code and database entry of array

Array Of Specs in database

a:12:{s:6:"Launch";a:2:{s:9:"Announced";s:12:"2019, August";s:6:"Status";s:9:"Available";}s:7:"Network";a:7:{s:10:"Technology";s:35:"GSM / CDMA / HSPA / EVDO / LTE / 5G";s:2:"3G";s:3:"Yes";s:2:"4G";s:3:"Yes";s:2:"5G";s:3:"Yes";s:5:"Speed";s:69:"HSPA 42.2/5.76 Mbps, LTE-A (7CA) Cat20 2048/150 Mbps, 5G (2+ Gbps DL)";s:4:"Edge";s:3:"Yes";s:4:"GPRS";s:3:"Yes";}s:4:"Body";a:5:{s:10:"Dimensions";s:45:"162.3 x 77.2 x 7.9 mm (6.39 x 3.04 x 0.31 in)";s:6:"Weight";s:15:"198 g (6.98 oz)";s:3:"SIM";s:3:"Yes";s:5:"Build";s:75:"Glass front (Gorilla Glass 6), glass back (Gorilla Glass 6), aluminum frame";s:6:"Others";s:143:"Samsung Pay (Visa, MasterCard certified) IP68 dust/water resistant (up to 1.5m for 30 mins) Stylus (Bluetooth integration, accelerometer, gyro)";}s:7:"Display";a:6:{s:4:"Type";s:49:"Dynamic AMOLED capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors";s:4:"Size";s:51:"6.8 inches, 114.0 cm2 (~91.0% screen-to-body ratio)";s:10:"Resolution";s:49:"1440 x 3040 pixels, 19:9 ratio (~498 ppi density)";s:10:"Multitouch";s:3:"Yes";s:10:"Protection";s:23:"Corning Gorilla Glass 6";s:6:"Others";s:25:"HDR10+, Always-on display";}s:8:"Platform";a:4:{s:2:"OS";s:60:"Android 9.0 (Pie), planned upgrade to Android 10.0; One UI 2";s:7:"Chipset";s:31:"Exynos 9825 (7 nm) - EMEA/LATAM";s:3:"CPU";s:80:"Octa-core (2x2.73 GHz Mongoose M4 & 2x2.4 GHz Cortex-A75 & 4x1.9 GHz Cortex-A55)";s:3:"GPU";s:26:"Mali-G76 MP12 - EMEA/LATAM";}s:6:"Memory";a:2:{s:9:"Card Slot";s:36:"microSD, up to 1 TB (dedicated slot)";s:8:"Internal";s:30:"256GB 12GB RAM, 512GB 12GB RAM";}s:6:"Camera";a:4:{s:7:"Primary";s:68:"12 MP, f/1.5-2.4, 27mm (wide), 1/2.55", 1.4µm, Dual Pixel PDAF, OIS";s:8:"Features";s:29:"LED flash, auto-HDR, panorama";s:5:"Video";s:107:"2160p@30/60fps, 1080p@30/60/240fps, 720p@960fps, HDR10+, dual-video rec., stereo sound rec., gyro-EIS & OIS";s:9:"Secondary";s:57:"10 MP, f/2.2, 26mm (wide), 1/3", 1.22µm, Dual Pixel PDAF";}s:5:"Sound";a:4:{s:11:"Alert types";N;s:11:"Loudspeaker";s:3:"Yes";s:9:"3.5mmJack";s:3:"Yes";s:6:"Others";s:95:"32-bit/384kHz audio Active noise cancellation with dedicated mic Dolby Atmos sound Tuned by AKG";}s:5:"Comms";a:6:{s:4:"WLAN";s:60:"Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac/ax, dual-band, Wi-Fi Direct, hotspot";s:9:"Bluetooth";s:19:"5.0, A2DP, LE, aptX";s:3:"GPS";s:38:"Yes, with A-GPS, GLONASS, BDS, GALILEO";s:3:"NFC";s:3:"Yes";s:5:"Radio";s:28:"FM radio (USA & Canada only)";s:3:"USB";s:36:"3.1, Type-C 1.0 reversible connector";}s:8:"Features";a:5:{s:7:"Sensors";s:91:"Fingerprint (under display, ultrasonic), accelerometer, gyro, proximity, compass, barometer";s:9:"Messaging";N;s:7:"Browser";N;s:4:"Java";N;s:6:"Others";N;}s:7:"Battery";a:4:{s:7:"Battery";s:37:"Non-removable Li-Ion 4300 mAh battery";s:8:"Stand-by";N;s:9:"Talk time";N;s:10:"Music play";N;}s:4:"Misc";a:5:{s:6:"Colors";s:33:"Aura Glow, Aura White, Aura Black";s:6:"SAR US";N;s:6:"SAR EU";N;s:11:"Price group";s:43:"€ 1,232.07 / $ 1,257.20 / £ 780.00";s:7:"Website";N;}}

Now the Query That i used in controller

```
 public function technologynetwork(Request $request)
    {
        $tech = $request->a;
//        return $tech;

        $devices = DB::table('devices')
            ->select('devices.*')
            ->from('devices', 'specs_array')
            ->where('specs_array','===', array_search("Yes",specs_array))
            ->orderBy('release_year', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('release_month', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(30);

        return view('frontend/'.$this->config->template.'/devices', [
            // global variables
            'config' => $this->config,
            'template_path' => $this->template_path,
            'logged_user_role' => $this->logged_user_role ?? NULL,

            // page variables
            'devices' => $devices,
            'count_all' => $devices->total(),
        ]);
    }
```

and my route is in web.php

```
Route::get('/spec/{a}', 'Frontend\DevicesController@technologynetwork');
```

and its frontend

```
  <dd><a href="{{url('spec/5G')}}">5G Phones</a></dd>
```

Anyone who can guide me how i can get any specs wise devices or how to search from an array

Comment: where Specs_array is database coulumn where array store

Answer (score 0):

Could not decode your Array Of Specs in database.
Assume you save specs in a column field called `specs_array`, it has this format: "5G":"Yes"

```
public function technologynetwork(Request $request)
    {
        $tech = $request->a;
        $search_string = '%"' . $tech . '":"Yes"%'; // = %"5G":"Yes"%

        $devices = DB::table('devices')
            ->select('devices.*')             // should remove this, not necessary
            ->from('devices', 'specs_array')  // should remove this, not necessary
            ->where('specs_array','LIKE', $search_string) // <= use LIKE for query
            ->orderBy('release_year', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('release_month', 'desc')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(30);

        return view('frontend/'.$this->config->template.'/devices', [
            // global variables
            'config' => $this->config,
            'template_path' => $this->template_path,
            'logged_user_role' => $this->logged_user_role ?? NULL,

            // page variables
            'devices' => $devices,
            'count_all' => $devices->total(),
        ]);
    }
```

When saving to database, `spec_arrays` becomes a string and should not be treated as array.

Comment: it's not worked for me please just look at the start of the question how to data save in the database coloumn

Comment: As I said: Could not decode your Array Of Specs in database. Please give more information about the table in database, such as schema, fields. Format Array Of Specs more easy to read

Comment: There are actually two arrays one is the specs array in which the title of technology saves like Network and the second one where the specs save like 4G,5G, etc.

Comment: Your code is absolutely correct but still cant get my required result look like like operator does not worked

Comment: Now i find where i am stuck actually i am creating a wrong Search String there is one extra space